# Database not updating after running this query

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbcommand

```
        String updateQuery = "UPDATE " + tableEmployeeContact + "  SET LastUpdate='@CurrentTimeStamp', EmployeeLastName='@EmployeeLastName', EmployeeFirstName='@EmployeeFirstName',EmployeeAddress1='@EmployeeAddress1',EmployeeAddress2='@EmployeeAddress2',EmployeeCity='@EmployeeCity',EmployeeState='@EmployeeState',EmployeeZip='@EmployeeZip',EmployeeHomePhone='@EmployeeHomePhone',EmployeeCellPhone='@EmployeeCellPhone',EmployeeHomeEmail='@EmployeeHomeEmail',EmergencyContactName='@EmergencyContactName',EmergencyContactRelationship='@EmergencyContactRelationship',EmergencyContactHomePhone='@EmergencyContactHomePhone',EmergencyContactCellPhone='@EmergencyContactCellPhone',EmergencyContactWorkPhone='@EmergencyContactWorkPhone' WHERE EmployeeLastName='@EmployeeLastName' AND EmployeeFirstName='@EmployeeFirstName'";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, connection);
            connection.Open();
            if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@CurrentTimeStamp", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = labelTimeStamp.Text.Trim();
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeLastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.LastName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeFirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.FirstName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeAddress1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeAddress1;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeAddress2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeAddress2;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeCity", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeCity;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeState", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeState;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeZip", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeZip;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeHomePhone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeHomePhone;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeCellPhone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeCellPhone;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeHomeEmail", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeHomeEmail;

                command.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyContactName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeECName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyContactRelationship", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeECRelationship;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyContactHomePhone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeECHomePhone;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyContactCellPhone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeECCellPhone;
                command.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyContactWorkPhone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeECWorkPhone;
                try
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
                    connection.Close();
                } catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Source);
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
                }
            }
        }
```

I get the messagebox saying **"Record Updated"** however after the application runs, I checked the database and the record did NOT update.

Not sure why it is not working. I made sure every value added is correct.

---

When I use this update query and comment all the Parameters under the if statement

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE " + tableEmployeeContact + "  SET LastUpdate = '" + labelTimeStamp.Text.Trim() + "', EmployeeLastName = '" + cm.LastName + "', EmployeeFirstName = '" + cm.FirstName + "', EmployeeAddress1 = '" + cm.EmployeeAddress1 + "', EmployeeAddress2 = '" + cm.EmployeeAddress2 + "', EmployeeCity = '" + cm.EmployeeCity + "', EmployeeState = '" + cm.EmployeeState + "', EmployeeZip = '" + cm.EmployeeZip + "', EmployeeHomePhone = '" + cm.EmployeeHomePhone + "', EmployeeCellPhone = '" + cm.EmployeeCellPhone + "', EmployeeHomeEmail = '" + cm.EmployeeHomeEmail + "', EmergencyContactName = '" + cm.EmployeeECName + "', EmergencyContactRelationship = '" + cm.EmployeeECRelationship + "', EmergencyContactHomePhone = '" + cm.EmployeeECHomePhone + "', EmergencyContactCellPhone = '" + cm.EmployeeECCellPhone + "', EmergencyContactWorkPhone = '" + cm.EmployeeECWorkPhone + "' WHERE EmployeeLastName='" + cm.LastName + "' AND EmployeeFirstName='" + cm.FirstName + "'";
```

The query works and everything gets updated. However I have been told that Parameters should be used instead of values directly in the SQL string.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct connection string? Are you inadvertently updating a different database?

Comment: If the command updated 0 records, this is also considered success. You need to check the number of rows updated by the oledbcommand - as indicated in PaulF's answer.

Comment: @itsme86 - a bad connection string would cause an exception

Comment: `WHERE EmployeeLastName='@EmployeeLastName' AND EmployeeFirstName='@EmployeeFirstName' ` means that they must not be changed => updateing them makes no sense. the `'`should not be there.

Comment: @PaulF I didn't say "bad" connection string. Maybe he has 2 copies of the database (test and prod) and it's pointing to the wrong one.

Comment: @JohnPrideaux the current time is always different with each run. (because time always ticks forward by a second)

Comment: i know its the right connection string because I used the same String to perform a SELECT operation when the app loads.

Comment: @softwareisfun Doesn't matter. What does matter is that your where clause is probably faulty. The return value of ExecuteNonQuery will give you the number of rows updated. This is probably 0.

Comment: does the WHERE clause need to be parameterized or can I use variables?

Comment: For production code, it should be parameterized, but for now, go ahead and use the variables so that you can get a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

See [OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), the parameters in the query are positional and not named so order is cricital and must match between the Parameters collection and the query. Use `?` as placeholders. You can still name the parameters in the collection although the name has no meaning when executing against Ms Access.

```
string updateQuery = "UPDATE " + tableEmployeeContact + @" SET 
     LastUpdate=?
    ,EmployeeAddress1=?
    ,EmployeeAddress2=?
    ,EmployeeCity=?
    ,EmployeeState=?
    ,EmployeeZip=?
    ,EmployeeHomePhone=?
    ,EmployeeCellPhone=?
    ,EmployeeHomeEmail=?
    ,EmergencyContactName=?
    ,EmergencyContactRelationship=?
    ,EmergencyContactHomePhone=?
    ,EmergencyContactCellPhone=?
    ,EmergencyContactWorkPhone=?
 WHERE EmployeeLastName=? AND EmployeeFirstName=?";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, connection);
    connection.Open();
    if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        // In MS Access the order of parameters is critical!!

        // I recommend replacing this with the below commented out parameter and changing your data type in MS Access accordingly. The type system is in place for a reason, not everything is a string.
        command.Parameters.Add("@CurrentTimeStamp", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = labelTimeStamp.Text.Trim();
        // command.Parameters.Add("@CurrentTimeStamp", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = DateTime.Now;

        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeAddress1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeAddress1;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeAddress2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeAddress2;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeCity", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeCity;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeState", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeState;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeZip", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeZip;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeHomePhone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeHomePhone;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeCellPhone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeCellPhone;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeHomeEmail", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeHomeEmail;

        command.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyContactName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeECName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyContactRelationship", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeECRelationship;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyContactHomePhone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeECHomePhone;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyContactCellPhone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeECCellPhone;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyContactWorkPhone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.EmployeeECWorkPhone;

        // Moved to the end and removed from the SET clause
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeLastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.LastName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeFirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cm.FirstName;

        try
        {
            var numberUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated = " + numberUpdated.ToString());
            // connection.Close(); // not needed as the connection is closed and disposed by the using block its wrapped in
        } catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Source);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
        }
    }
}
```

---

- Notice that when you had this tick marks around your parameters like `'@EmployeeAddress1'` I changed it to this `@EmployeeAddress1` (no `'` symbol around the parameter)
- I removed 2 parameters from the SET clause. You had them double in your query but not listed double in your parameters, this would cause a problem with Ms Access.
- Why are you specifying `CurrentTimeStamp` as a varchar instead of some type of datetime type?

Answer (score 0):

First make a change to get the actual number of rows updated.

This will confirm if the update happened.

```
var rowCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Since it is not updating are you using a database that has Auto Commit off? SQL Server typically autocommit turned on, Oracle it is off and in this case you need to use a transaction and commit.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracletransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: its an access database. I never heard of Auto Commit in MSACCESS. Where can I look for it?

Comment: This would not apply to access. Did you confirm the actual row count > 0?